# How am I able to get Opportunity Team Members onto an Email template?

Tags: email, template

I would like members from the Opportunity Teams from Team Role 'Solutions Consultant' only, to be displayed on an HTML Visualforce email template.

I would like the code to have the same format as:

```
<pre>
    </tr>
    <tr > 
    <td bgcolor="#00A6C3"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b><i>Lead Source:</i></b></font></td>
    <td>{!relatedTo.LeadSource}  </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr > 

</pre>
```

Comment: You'll need to write a VF component with a controller to retrieve the opp team members

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Here are some good starting points:  https://www.google.com/search?q=visualforce+email+template+component+controller&oq=visualforce+email+template+component+controller&aqs=chrome..69i57.9542j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Opportunity is the "relatedTo" attribute, you can do this without a component or controller:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.OpportunityContactRoles}" var="oppConRole">
  <apex:outputText rendered="{!oppConRole.Role='Solutions Consultant'}">
    <tr><td>{!oppConRole.Contact.Name}</td></tr>
  </apex:outputText>
</apex:repeat>
```